# Using multiple Clone methods.. Java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, sorting, clone

I am trying to create this program that has a main class test001 that basically makes a shallow copy of Appointment objects and another main class test002 that makes a deep copy of  it.. So basically i need to add the codes in Appointment class to support both of them.. Here is what i put in but the problem is, i am getting an error  saying that i have already used clone.. What do i do? first clone() is for shallow and the second one is for deep copy

```
 public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();

 }
 public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
 {
     Appointment ap = (Appointment) super.clone();

     ap.date = (Date) date.clone();

     return ap;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give your methods different namens, the signature is exactly the same: same method name, same parameters, same return type....
How should the compiler know which method to choose? So just rename one of the methods.

Comment: u mean like instead of clone i can use clone1? Will that still work?

Comment: Just name one method cloneShallow and one cloneDeep for example. You have to try then, but its definitely better as now ;)

Comment: Thanks! Btw I just have one more question I was hoping to get an answer to.. Basically, I created this Date class that has 3 attributes, day,month,year and then i used this date class in appointments class like this: private Date date;.. Now the thing is, i have to use setters and getters to get values from the user.. For attributes I know how to handle it. just declare the object and type in ap.setName("Liam") or ap.setAge(8); etc. But how do i do it with setDate()? :/

Comment: Please mark my solution as correct if it helped you.
I would suggest you to open a new question for your second question. It is hard to find out what you mean without any code. Do you mean a constructor? In a self defined Date-Object you don't want to have a setDate() Method. Just setDay() setMonth() and setYear(). You can make a setDate like this if you don't want to use a constructor: setDate(int year, int month, int day){this.year=year;this.month=month;this.day=day;} or setDate(Date other){this.year = other.year;this.month=other.month;this.day=other.day;}